# Error fatal: Not a valid object name origin on rasp pi

Tags: bash, git

I am trying to make a script that will autopull from a git repo every hour if there are changes. It is running on a raspberry pi.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    VAR=$(git merge-base origin master)
    VAR2=$(git rev-parse origin)

    if [ "$VAR" == $VAR2 ]; 
    then
        echo "hi"
        git pull
    else
        echo "no"
    fi
```

That is my code. It is returning these errors

fatal: Not a valid object name origin
fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:

```
git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]
```

However, the 2 commands above which the errors come from, run fine on my windows machine. What is the problem here?

**Solution**
I found that in my git branch -a I did not have a head branch, so I created one with
        git symbolic-ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD refs/remotes/origin/master

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure of your set up... But *probably* origin is a remote, not a branch.... And if that is the case, both merge-base and rev-parse will fail because of that. Merge-base needs at least 2 branches or revisions to work ... rev-parse needs one branch. If you try to use a remote as one of the arguments, one explosion is to be expected.

Comment: `origin` will parse as `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` at step 6 of the name-to-hash-ID resolution protocol (see [gitrevisions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions)), *provided* `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` exists. It probably makes more sense to use `origin/master master` here though.